# Reducing augmented matrices in SymPy

Tags: python, matrix, sympy

A common task in Linear Algebra (101) is to row-reduce an "augmented matrix" `[A | b]` where `b` is the right hand side of the linear system `Ax=b`.  Often, we want to row reduce using symbolic variables for `b`.  The entries in the row-reduced `b` will reveal any compatibility conditions on the components of `b` that are needed to obtain a solution to the linear system.

If `A` has full row rank and `b` contains symbolic variables, the Sympy function `rref()` will return the expected results

```
import sympy as sp
from pprint import pprint

b = sp.symbols('b_(0:3)',real=True)

A = sp.Matrix(2,2,[1,0,-1,1])
B = sp.Matrix(2,1,b[0:2])
A_aug = sp.Matrix.hstack(A,B)

# Augmented matrix
print("Augumented matrix [A,b] (A has full row rank)")
pprint(A_aug)
print("")

# Row reduced Echelon form (correct/expected)
print("Row-reduced form (correct)")
pprint(A_aug.rref())
```

The results are as expected :

```
Augumented matrix [A,b] (A has full row rank )
Matrix([
[ 1, 0, b_0],
[-1, 1, b_1]])

Row-reduced form (correct/expected)
(Matrix([
[1, 0,       b_0],
[0, 1, b_0 + b_1]]), (0, 1))
```

However, when trying this on a matrix `A` that does not have full row rank, the row-reduction is too aggressive, and SymPy will reduce the column(s) with symbolic variables to obtain additional pivot rows.

```
# A does not have full row rank
A = sp.Matrix(3,2,[1,0,-1,1,0,-1])
B = sp.Matrix(3,1,b)

A_aug = sp.Matrix.hstack(A,B)
print("Augmented matrix (A is row-rank deficient)")
pprint(A_aug)
print("")

print("Row-reduced form (Sympy)")
pprint(A_aug.rref())
```

Results :

```
Augmented matrix (A is row-rank deficient)
Matrix([
[ 1,  0, b_0],
[-1,  1, b_1],
[ 0, -1, b_2]])

Row-reduced form (Sympy)
(Matrix([
[1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1]]), (0, 1, 2))
```

Sympy interprets that last column as a "pivot column", even though in Linear algebra 101, the final step that would turn the last column into a pivot column is ignored.

The results I expect/was hoping for are :

```
Row-reduced form (expected)
Matrix([
[1, 0,             b_0],
[0, 1,       b_0 + b_1],
[0, 0, b_0 + b_1 + b_2]])
```

The last entry in the last column is useful, since it gives us a compatibility condition on the entries in the right hand side vector.

It seems that what is needed is a way to indicate potential pivot columns ahead of time so that SymPy ignores non-pivot columns when row-reducing.

**UPDATE:** Sympy `rref()` will produced expected results for matrices of full row rank.

```
A_aug = [A|b]
Matrix([
[1, 2, 3,  5, b_1],
[2, 4, 8, 12, b_2],
[3, 6, 7, 12, b_3]])

A_aug.rref()
Matrix([
[1, 2, 0, 0, -6*b_1 + b_2/2 + 2*b_3],
[0, 0, 1, 0, -6*b_1 + 3*b_2/2 + b_3],
[0, 0, 0, 1,      5*b_1 - b_2 - b_3]])
```

If `A` is missing pivot rows, Sympy will reduce symbolic variables in the augmented columns to produce the missing pivot rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the solution @smichr proposed, here is a general approach (for small matrices, at least) for situations in which the `rank(A) < A.rows`.

```
import sympy as sp
from pprint import pprint

def rref_aug(A, B):
    n,m = A.rows,A.cols
    p,q = B.rows,B.cols
    assert n == p, 'A and B must have the same number of rows'
    r = A.rank()
    if r < n:
        A11 = A[:r, :]    # Interpret A as a 2x1 block matrix
        A21 = A[r:, :]
        O = sp.zeros(r, n-r)
        I = sp.eye(n-r)
        Apad = sp.Matrix([[A11,O],[A21,I]])
        R,pv = sp.Matrix.hstack(Apad, B).rref()       
        return sp.Matrix.hstack(R[:,:m],R[:,-q:]),pv[:r]
    return sp.Matrix.hstack(A,B).rref()
```

Here is an example :

```
b = sp.symbols('b_(1:4)',real=True)
B = sp.Matrix(3,1,b)

print("A = ")
A = sp.Matrix(3,4,[1,3,0,2,\
                   0,0,1,4,\
                   1,3,1,6])

pprint(A)
print("")

R,pv = rref_aug(A,B)

print("rref_aug(A,B) = ")
pprint(R)
print("")

pprint(pv)
```

and the results

```
A = 
Matrix([
[1, 3, 0, 2],
[0, 0, 1, 4],
[1, 3, 1, 6]])

rref_aug(A,B) = 
Matrix([
[1, 3, 0, 2,              b_1],
[0, 0, 1, 4,              b_2],
[0, 0, 0, 0, -b_1 - b_2 + b_3]])

pivots
(0, 2)
```

The trick that @mchir proposed is to `hstack` pivot rows zeros and the non-pivot rows with an identity matrix. This padded `A` has full row rank, and so SymPy will not need to rely on symbolic variables in `b` to obtain additional pivots.

In the example above, the single non-pivot row in `A` is appended with `1x1` identity matrix and zeros are padded in the final column. The resulting padded matrix `Apad` is given by

```
Matrix([
[1, 3, 0, 2, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 4, 0],
[1, 3, 1, 6, 1]])
```

Rather than identify pivot columns, this approach identifies pivot rows as the first `r` rows of `A`.   This should handle most linear algebra 101 problems, although its reliance on the rank of `A` is not ideal.

This approach assumes that `A` has only numeric data, and that  `B` contains any symbolic variables.

Comment: Could you only fall back to the rank only in cases when `A.cols > A.rows`?

Comment: No - consider the case A=ones(2,2) - a square matrix with rank 1.  `Matrix.rref()`  applied to an augmented matrix `[A|b]` returns `[1,1,0;0,0,1]`.

Comment: The echelon form itself is rank-revealing, so one could eliminate the call to rank by row reductions, but then this is probably what A.rank() is already doing.

Comment: I recommend accepting your answer as the answer. This seems to be the most robust solution.

Comment: If you read the comment [here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/25661#issuecomment-1719217166) you will find that this method will not always work. There is also a suggestion to simply pad with an identity matrix that has the same number of rows as A.

Comment: The approach I suggested only works if the first 'r' rows are pivot rows.  So a more general solution should allow for row exchanges.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you wanted:

```
In [4]: A_aug
Out[4]: 
⎡1   0   b₀⎤
⎢          ⎥
⎢-1  1   b₁⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎣0   -1  b₂⎦

In [5]: A_aug.echelon_form()
Out[5]: 
⎡1  0       b₀     ⎤
⎢                  ⎥
⎢0  1    b₀ + b₁   ⎥
⎢                  ⎥
⎣0  0  b₀ + b₁ + b₂⎦
```

I expect that this will still not do what you want if you increase the number of rows further though. In general with SymPy I might approach this problem with Groebner bases but those are unlikely to be what you want in linear algebra 101...

I agree that it would in general be good to have a parameter that signifies how many columns should be interpreted as the lhs of an augmented matrix. Best to open an issue on GitHub to suggest a change to that though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to check out `echelon_form`.  I tried it on a 4x3 augmented matrix, and no matter what the fourth row is, always returns all zeros in the fourth row of the echelon form.  Seems that a "general" RREF should return one of four forms : [I], [I, F], [I; 0] or [I, F; 0, 0] (see Strang).  But this is probably easier said than done!

Comment: This is being discussed on GitHub: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/25661

Comment: Note also this change which makes it easier to use "manual" row operations: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/25596

Answer (score 1):

You could use rref to handle the square part and then do the rest by hand:

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> b1,b2,b3,b4 = symbols('b1:5')

def rref1(A, B):
  # limit rref to min(A.rows, A.cols) rows and finish
  # remainder by hand
  if A.rows > A.cols:
   sq = A[:A.cols, :]
   red = Matrix.hstack(sq, B[:A.cols,:]).rref()[0]
   assert red[:,:-1] == eye(A.cols)
   red = Matrix.vstack(red, zeros(A.rows-A.cols, A.cols + 1))
   for i in range(A.cols, A.rows):
    v = B[i]
    for j in range(A.cols):
        v -= A[i,j]*red[j,-1]
    red[i,-1] = v
   return red
  return Matrix.hstack(A, B).rref()[0]

>>> A
Matrix([
[ 1,  0],
[-1,  1],
[ 0, -1]])
>>> B
Matrix([
[b1],
[b2],
[b3]])
>>> rref1(A,B)
Matrix([
[1, 0,           b1],
[0, 1,      b1 + b2],
[0, 0, b1 + b2 + b3]])
>>> A1,B1
(Matrix([
[ 1,  0],
[-1,  1],
[ 0, -1],
[ 1,  1]]), Matrix([
[b1],
[b2],
[b3],
[b4]]))
>>> rref1(A1,B1)
Matrix([
[1, 0,              b1],
[0, 1,         b1 + b2],
[0, 0,    b1 + b2 + b3],
[0, 0, -2*b1 - b2 + b4]])
>>> a,b
(Matrix([
[1, -1,  0],
[0,  1, -1]]), Matrix([
[b1],
[b2]]))
>>> rref1(a,b)
Matrix([
[1, 0, -1, b1 + b2],
[0, 1, -1,      b2]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could "eye-pad" your non-square matrix before calling `rref` by adding an identity matrix to make your tall matrix square (since the wide or square matrix A are already handled as you would like):

```py
def rref(A, B):
    assert A.rows == B.rows
    if A.rows > A.cols:
        a = A[:A.cols, :]
        c = A[A.cols:, :]
        b = zeros(a.rows, A.rows - A.cols)
        d = eye(c.rows)
        return Matrix.hstack(Matrix([[a,b],[c,d]]), B).rref()
    return Matrix.hstack(A,B).rref()
```

and then

```py
>>> A = Matrix([[1, 0], [-1, 1], [0, -1], [1, 1]])
>>> b = Matrix([[x, 1], [y, 2], [z, 3], [t, 4]])  # do 2 RHS
>>> print(rref(A, b))
(Matrix([
[1, 0, 0, 0,           x, 1],
[0, 1, 0, 0,       x + y, 3],
[0, 0, 1, 0,   x + y + z, 6],
[0, 0, 0, 1, t - 2*x - y, 0]]), (0, 1, 2, 3))
```